# RemoteViews setOnClickPendingIntent overwrites the Intent for the same view ID even in different notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

My app needs to show multiple notifications. Each notification uses the same custom layout xml which has a button that fires an intent with an extra int, a number X, which is unique for each notification.

This is done by  RemoteViews, so I do something like this for each of my notification:

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(...);
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.myButton, myIntentWithUniqueId)
Notification myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setContent(remoteViews)
    ...
    .build();
```

I use different id's when showing the notification

```
notificationManager.notify(someUniqueId, myNotification)
```

I found that even I can show multiple notifications, all of the buttons in all notifications have the same intent as the last notification being shown. It's verified by seeing the intent in each notification contains the same extra int X when the button in each of the notification is pressed.

Is this a bug or by design?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may solve this. Add your pendingintents to TaskStackBuilder. 
This will retrieve pendingintent which is associated to perticular notification. Example..

```
android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

//                        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
                        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
                        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(notificationid, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                        //resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, notificationid, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

Or try using broadcasting intent like,

```
Intent resultDismissintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationCancelReceiver.class);
 resultDismissintent.putExtra("notificationId", notificationid);
 resultDismissintent.putExtras(resultIntent.getExtras());

 PendingIntent resultCancelPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, notificationid, resultDismissintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.tv_view, resultCancelPendingIntent);
 contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.tv_cancel, resultPendingIntent);
```

Comment: I don't quite get how you solve the issue by using a TaskStackBuilder. It seems to me you are calling NotificationBuilder#setContentIntent, but as you can see my intent is actually set in RemoteViews for a specific View (I actually has three buttons in the RemoteViews, but I think it's easier to ask the question with one button), so I am not setting an intent for my notification.